# A continuum of independent random variables

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

How can one construct a probability space that supports a **continuum** of independent random variables?

Comment: Kolmogorov's extension theorem: http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/Notes/Kolmogorov.pdf

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on Chris's hint, it follows from KET that as soon as you define finite-dimensional distributions which satisfy two simple properties, you can construct a measure on the product space which have those finite-dimensional distributions as marginals. Now, let us consider $\xi_t$ be a random variable for $t\in[0,1]$ where $\xi_t$ has a distribution $\mu_t$  and $\xi_t\perp\xi_s$ whenever $s\neq t$. Then
$$
  \nu_{t_1,\dots,t_n}(A_1\times \dots\times A_n) := \prod_{i=1}^n\mu_{t_i}(A_i)
$$
are the correspondent finite-dimensional distributions. You can easily check that they satisfy all the required properties needed to apply KET.

Comment: Thanks, Chris Janjigian and Ilya, that's what I was looking for! I am I correct in thinking that this also allows one to construct a continuum of absolutely general random elements? Say a continuum of independent copies of BM?

Comment: @mStudent: check out the assumptions on the KET: there are some topological conditions, so spaces for random elements has to be good enough topological spaces.